# Periodic NPE In Kafka Streams Processor Context

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Using kafka-streams 0.10.0.0, I am periodically seeing a null pointer exception in the StreamTask when forwarding a message. It varies between 10% to 50% of the invocations. The NPE occurs in this method:

```
public <K, V> void forward(K key, V value) {
    ProcessorNode thisNode = currNode;
    try {
        for (ProcessorNode childNode : (List<ProcessorNode<K, V>>) thisNode.children()) {
            currNode = childNode;
            childNode.process(key, value);
        }
    } finally {
        currNode = thisNode;
    }
}
```

It seems that in some cases, the **thisNode** field is null. Any idea what might be causing this ? The stack trace is below.

```
[ERROR] 2016-08-21 14:50:39.288 [StreamThread-1] StreamedMetricMeter - Forwarding failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.forward(StreamTask.java:336) ~[kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:187) ~[kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.heliosapm.streams.metrics.processors.AbstractStreamedMetricProcessor.forward(AbstractStreamedMetricProcessor.java:552) [classes/:?]
    at com.heliosapm.streams.metrics.processors.impl.StreamedMetricMeter.doProcess(StreamedMetricMeter.java:89) [classes/:?]
    at com.heliosapm.streams.metrics.processors.impl.StreamedMetricMeter.doProcess(StreamedMetricMeter.java:1) [classes/:?]
    at com.heliosapm.streams.metrics.processors.AbstractStreamedMetricProcessor.process(AbstractStreamedMetricProcessor.java:166) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:68) [kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.forward(StreamTask.java:338) [kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:187) [kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:64) [kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:174) [kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:320) [kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:218) [kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar:?]
```

Comment: Can you share your topology code? Did you try `0.10.0.1` ?

Comment: Figured it out. See answer. Thanks for chiming in. That programmer error was so egregious, once I realized, I did not test with 0.10.0.1.

Comment: By the way, this issue also occurs in `0.10.2.1`. 
Your answer was a lifesaver, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that my [ProcessorSupplier](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorSupplier.html)s were returning the same instance of the Processor for every call to [get](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorSupplier.html#get()). In turn, the Kafka Streams engine was attempting to create multiple processor instances, which I have no doubt created a multi-threaded dumpster fire. Note to the similarly unwary.... **ProcessorSupplier.get()** should return a new instance of a processor on each call.

Comment: Good call. Thanks !

Comment: @Nicholas:  Are you still seeing this error? I am facing a similar issue; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280229/npe-while-doing-context-forward-using-low-level-kafka-stream-api