# NPE while doing context.forward() using low-level Kafka Stream API

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have built a plain Kafka streams API using Low-level Kafka API. The topology is linear.

p1 -> p2 -> p3

While doing context.forward(), I am getting NPE, snippet here:

```
NAjava.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)

...
```

I am using Kafka Stream 2.3.0.

I see a similar SO question [here][1], and the question is based on the very old version. So, not sure if this is the same error?

### Edit

I am putting some more info, keeping the Gist of what I am doing

```
public class SP1Processor implements StreamProcessor {

private StreamProcessingContext ctxt;

// In init(), create a single thread pool
// which does some processing and sends the
// data to next processor
@Override
void init(StreamProcessingContext ctxt) {

      this.ctxt = ctxt;

     // Create a thread pool, do some work
     // and then do this.ctxt.forward(K,V)

    // Not showing code of Thread pool
    // Strangely, inside this thread pool,
    // this.ctxt isn't same what I see in process()
    // shouldn't it be same? ctxt is member variable
    // and shouldn't it be same
    // this.ctxt.forward(K,V) here in this thread pool is causing NPE
    // why does it happen?
    this.ctxt.forward(K,V);

}

@Override
void process(K,V) {

   // Here do some processing and go to the next processor chain
   // This works fine
   this.ctxt.forward(K,V);
}

}

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067846/periodic-npe-in-kafka-streams-processor-context
```

Comment: Could you add code sinpped?

Comment: @BartoszWardziński: I have added code snippet. In process() , ctxt.forward() works well; however, in init(), I'm spawning a thread pool, and in there when I do ctxt.forward(), it's causing NPE. ctxt itself isn't null in either process() or in thread pool, but strangely theey aren't same

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it could be the same issue as the linked question, although we are talking about a much more contemporary version in your case.
Make sure that `ProcessorSupplier.get()` returns a new instance each time it is called.

Comment: `ProcessorSupplier.get()` is this called during topology building only or when we do context.forward() as well?

Comment: I added code snippet, pl have a look and let me know if there is something unusual?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create any thread pool inside Processor or DSL calls.
Parallelism is managed in KafkaStreams by `num.stream.threads`, number of partitions and number of instances.

`ctxt` is the same but its fields/members might be different (ex. `currentNode`) - might be change by different threads.